# Isomorphic elliptic curves (abelian varieties) over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-groups, abelian-varieties

For two elliptic curves $E_1, E_2$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, we assume $E_1$ and $E_2$ are isomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$, then how to prove they are isomorphic over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Also, can we get the same conclusion if we replace elliptic curves by abelian varieties? Here, an abelian variety by definition is a complete connected group variety.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the curves be
$$E_i:\qquad y^2=x^3+a_ix+b_i$$
for $i=1$, $2$. If they are isomorphic over $\Bbb C$ then there is a non-zero
complex number $t$ with $a_2=t^4a_1$ and $b_2=t^6b_1$. If $a_1\ne0$ then $t^4$
is rational and $t\in\overline{\Bbb Q}$. Likewise if $b_1\ne0$. But if $a_1=b_1=0$
then $E_1$ wasn't an elliptic curve.

Comment: Could you please see the accepted answer of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13989/two-questions-on-isomorphic-elliptic-curves/13997#13997)? stankewicz said this can be seen with Lefschetz principle. Could you explain this?